# Disaggregate / increase raster resolution and distribute initial cell values to new cells through division

Tags: r, raster, spatial, resolution, r-raster

Is there a way to increase the resolution of a raster for example from 0.5 degree to 0.25 degree with the values from the 0.5 degree cells being distributed into the new 0.25 degree cells? For example, if a 0.5 degree cell has a value of 8, the four 0.25 degree cell get a value of 2 (8/4)? Thanks a lot for your help!

```
r <- raster(ncol=2, nrow=2)
r[] <- 8
r2 <- disaggregate(r, fact=2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can divide by 4, as follows

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=2, nrow=2, vals=8)
r2 <- disaggregate(r, fact=2) / 4
```